# Finding the motion of an Object (solution needed)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, physics

A baseball player hits a pitched ball so that its velocity reverses direction from 30m/s to 40m/s. The bat moves at an average velocity of 30m/s, and it is in contact with the ball for a distance of 0.05m. What is the average acceleration of the ball while it is in contact with the bat?

Answer (score 0):

Δv = 40 m/s - (-30 m/s) = 70 m/s

Δt = 0.05 m / (30 m/s) = 1/600 s

a_avg = Δv/Δt = 42, 000 m/s^2